# Inserting new features to PG\PostGIS table with generated column using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, qgis-3

I'm using PG 12.2 with PostGIS 3.0.0, and I've created a table with a [generated column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html):

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.test1
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('test1_id_seq1'::regclass),
    geom geometry(Polygon,3857),
    area_sqrm double precision GENERATED ALWAYS AS (st_area(geom)) STORED,
    CONSTRAINT test1_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I want to create new features in this table using QGIS 3.12.2. Therefore I did the following steps:

1. Import table into QGIS project
2. Toggled editing
3. Sketched new valid geometry polygon entity
4. Approved QGIS default form
   [image: QGIS default form]
5. Saved layer edits

This last step resulted with the following error:

```sql
Could not commit changes to layer test1

Errors: ERROR: 1 feature(s) not added.

  Provider errors:
      PostGIS error while adding features: ERROR:  column "geom" does not exist
    LINE 1: ...") VALUES (st_geomfromwkb($1::bytea,3857),st_area(geom)) RET...
                                                                 ^
    HINT:  There is a column named "geom" in table "test1", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
```

After omitting the default value QGIS applied for the `area_sqrm` column, I tried to save again. This resulted with the following error:

```sql
Could not commit changes to layer test1

Errors: ERROR: 1 feature(s) not added.

  Provider errors:
      PostGIS error while adding features: ERROR:  cannot insert into column "area_sqrm"
    DETAIL:  Column "area_sqrm" is a generated column.
```

How can I create new features using QGIS, and let their generated columns to be populated DB-wise?

In this case, it can be thought as working with ArcGIS' FGDB feature class which has two dedicated computed geometry fields: shape_area; shape_length. In its environment, the two fields are being computed after creation and altered after the entity's geometry is edited.

Comment: What if you leave both fields blank?

Comment: @HeikkiVesanto I'm still getting the same errors.

Comment: does it work with the keyword `DEFAULT`? In pure SQL it is allowed to have insert/update on generated columns with this keyword

Comment: If I understand you right, @JGH, after assigning ```DEFAULT``` to QGIS attribute form default value setting, I'm getting the same first error, that is: Could not commit changes to layer test1

Errors: ERROR: 1 feature(s) not added.
    Provider errors:
      PostGIS error while adding features: ERROR:  column "geom" does not exist
    LINE 1: ...") VALUES (st_geomfromwkb($1::bytea,3857),st_area(geom)) RET...
                                                                 ^
    HINT: There is a column named "geom" in table "test1", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query

Comment: what if you write `default` in the feature attribute form (the 1st image in your post)

Comment: ///Hi @JGH, sorry for the long delay/// QGIS prevents me from inserting ```DEFAULT``` value to the new feature's ```area_sqrm``` field in the attribute form. It only lets me to insert numeric characters (1-9 and e) or to remove default value. The second option leave the new feature's attribute form with a greyed ```st_area(geom)``` in the ```area_sqrm`` field.

Comment: Toggling the ```Evaluate default values on provider side``` in the ```Project Properties > Data Sources``` section, results with a greyed ```NULL``` value but nonetheless raises the second discussed error upon saving. That is:  
Layer test1 : PostGIS error while adding features: ERROR: cannot insert into column "area_sqrm"
             DETAIL: Column "area_sqrm" is a generated column.

Comment: It looks like this issue is being addressed in [this](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/35995) thread in GitHub. I hope it'll be resolved in 3.14.0.

Comment: Making it more accurate: it was initially addressed in this [issue thread](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/32898 "Save fails on PostGIS tables containing a generated (GENERATED AS) column") and resolved in [this PR](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/35995 "Save features into PostgreSQL 12+ tables with GENERATED columns").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now possible in the development version (and soon in QGIS 3.14) due the efforts made in [this PR](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/35995). One can now save features of tables containing generated columns.